# Postgresql date formatting

Tags: postgresql, date, formatting, postgresql-8.4

I have a dataset (in .tsv format) where one of the columns is **date of birth**. However, the data is old, and not all dates are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Some entries just have their year of birth (month and day of birth are missing) and are in the format `YYYY-##-##` (literally `##`'s are already inserted in the data wherever only year is known). I wish to load this dataset into my **postgres** database, with the **date of birth** column with data type as `date` and not `string`, so that I can do comparison on dates.
A small sample is shown below. (Irrelevant columns of data are not shown)

```
1924-##-##
1965-09-04
1944-11-05
1951-##-##
-388-##-##
1893-01-26
1037-##-##
```

Directly bulk loading the dataset *obviously* gives an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "1924-##-##"
LINE 1: insert into d values ('1924-##-##');
                              ^
```

The dataset is quite large, having around 6 crore entries. Currently I am thinking of running a script for replacing these `##`'s with `01` and then inserting the modified data into the database. But I don't like this idea for -

1. This is time consuming.
2. This is disk-space consuming (as I would like to keep the original "umtampered" data)
3. Also, not all my data would be genuine in my database.

Is there any way I can ask postgres to somehow just take the dates as it is, by just ignoring the `##'s (and just keeping the year where the months and days are missing) ?
Or can there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create in your table two columns, one for the originally entered value (type of varchar), and one for calculation (type date).

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
 id INT,
 -- OTHER DETAILS
 dob_entered    VARCHAR,
 dob_parsed DATE
);
```

You can then use on an Insert trigger to automatically populate the date field from the varchar, with an update trigger to handle any changes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION evaluate_dob_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.dob_parsed = CAST(REPLACE(NEW.dob_entered,'##','01') AS DATE);
    RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER parse_dob 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE evaluate_dob_date();
```

This will mean that you store both the originally entered data untouched for verification, while still having a date field in the database suitable for sorting and comparing etc.  Also, by extending the `evaluate_dob_date()` function you can match against different cases as you find them, while still being able to reject records that are genuinely invalid.

[Postgresql triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/triggers.html)

Comment: Upvoted but just a small additional note, you don't actually have to store the date_parsed.  You can do something like a table method and then constrain on the output of that, so you know your input dates always parse.  For more on table methods, see this blog piece I wrote: http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-2-intro-to.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. Once you fetch the data from the database, replace all occurrences of # in your server side script and then compare the dates. (You could also replace the data dynamically in the table itself without modifying the existing data using an if condition in the query)
2. Ignore the dates that have a #. That way you can compare only valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the `#` characters, the only chance I see is to import that into a `varchar` column.

If you absolutely need the information as a date, you might get away with a view that does the conversion and only selects those rows where there is no `#` in the column.

Something like

```
SELECT to_date(dob,'YYYY-MM-DD') as dob_date
FROM your_table
WHERE substr(dob,6,2) <> '##';
```

If you do that on a regular basis, you might want to consider an index on that expression to speed up the selection:

```
CREATE INDEX dob_check ON your_table( substr(dob,6,2) );
```

Note that the expression in your select must match *exactly* the expression in the index in order to be usable by the query planer.

If you want to "convert" the data into a valid date during retrieval, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT case 
         case when substr(dob,6,2) = '##' then to_date(substr(dob,1,5)||'01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         else to_date(dob,'YYYY-MM-DD')
       end as dob_date
FROM your_table;
```